# Information about @clr/angular@next

Tags: vmware-clarity

both [Angular Blog](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/gnomeontherun/status/992164233369485312) mention is possible to use @clr/angular with Angular v6 using `@clr/angular@next`

Can we have details about that version? which version/branch in GitHub it refers to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@clr/angular@next` is a tag for one of our 0.11 releases that supports the `ng add` functionality. There is a PR open right now that is designed to bring Clarity up to speed with RXJS 6 changes (which were the only real issues for Angular 6). https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/2238

You can always look up what a tag references on NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/@clr/angular, and we tag our releases in GitHub as well for tracking purposes.

After this PR is merged, we will start doing beta releases for 0.12, which will be fully Angular 6 compatible. However, using the 0.11 release with the RXJS compat layer should also work fine. NPM will spit out a few warnings that most likely can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I found I have to install `rxjs-compat`. Actually @next points to 0.11.5

Comment: Yes, we weren't fully ready for the Angular 6 release so this is required until we can release the @next update.